# scala Read an array of objects from a configuration file

Tags: scala, file-io, json-deserialization

I have a config file and I need to access to the values of "first" and "second" in this config file.

```
"config":
[

    {
        "first": ["a"],
        "second": "b"
    },

    {
        "first": ["c","d"],
        "second": "e"
    },

    {
        "first": ["f,g"],
        "second": "h"
    }

]
```

I like to do something like :

```
config = getObjectList("config")

config.foreach(conf <- config){

   first = //recover the value of first
   second = //recover the value of second

}
```

Comment: What type is returned by getconfiglist. Your config looks like json. Maybe circe or play-json helps you here.

Comment: Sorry, it's an objectList, i edit the post

Comment: @dor he was asking for the format of the text file. Determine the format and parse the file, solving the problem.

Comment: it's a .json file, @Aluan :can you explain more please

Comment: Basically, just read the text file using the built in file io, then parse it using a json parser like Jackson.